# Need assistance understanding URL aliasing to deliver text files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, drupal

This is my first time setting up an alias and have found several examples on how to use it but for what ever reason I'm still not 100% confident on how the syntax should work. I've been spending the majority of today searching for a concrete example but have had no luck. I guess I really need some hand holding on this one, haha. Here are some of the examples I found for readers that run across this post:

httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html

net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/apache-aliasing-and-redirection/

serverfault.com/questions/362040/accessing-directories-outside-of-documentroot

Here is my situation:
First the web root for the remote server I am working with is:

```
'/data1/home/spaceweather/htdoc'
```

The archive of data files that I want to link to start at this location:

```
'/data1/public'
```

I have approximately 20,000 text files that will eventually be searchable by the public via the website I am developing. The directory structure containing all the files looks like:

```
data1/
     /public/
            /cases/
                  /grid108/
                          <here there are folders, one for every day of the year>
                          <which contains the text files>
                  /grid112/
                          <here there are folders, one for every day of the year>
                          <which contains the text files>
                  /grid180/
                          <here there are folders, one for every day of the year>
                          <which contains the text files>
```

an example path all the way to a single text file looks something like this:

```
'/data1/public/cases/grid108/144/txt/channel_dataout_2013_144_0000.log'
```

the above path is definitely outside of my web root folder so this is why I figure aliasing is the best option.  The guides online mention that to create an alias I need to modify my .htaccess file. So I went ahead and found my .htaccess file (code is shown below).  You will notice the words Drupal sprinkled about in the below code and that is because the website I am making is powered by Drupal.

my .htaccess file:

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig\.save)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# Override PHP settings that cannot be changed at runtime. See
# sites/default/default.settings.php and drupal_environment_initialize() in
# includes/bootstrap.inc for settings that can be changed at runtime.

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
  php_flag register_globals                 off
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
    # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
  # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
  # you don't bounce between http and https.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

  # Make sure Authorization HTTP header is available to PHP
  # even when running as CGI or FastCGI.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
  # includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or
  # Git to store control files. Files whose names begin with a period, as well
  # as the control files used by CVS, are protected by the FilesMatch directive
  # above.
  #
  # NOTE: This only works when mod_rewrite is loaded. Without mod_rewrite, it is
  # not possible to block access to entire directories from .htaccess, because
  # <DirectoryMatch> is not allowed here.
  #
  # If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
  # directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
  # downloaded.
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

now comes the part where I am lost. Here is what I'm assuming will work.  If I start at the last line of code in the above file and put `Alias /cases/data/ "/data1/public/cases/"` this will redirect the URL:

`apollo.tbc.iit.edu/~spaceweather/cases/data/grid108/144/txt/channel_dataout_2013_144_0000.log`

to

`apollo.tbc.iit.edu/~spaceweather/data1/public/cases/grid108/144/txt/channel_dataout_2013_144_0000.log`

This is why this method doesnt make sense to me. How does this code tell the web server to deliver files outside of the web root?  How can I get a URL that looks like:

`apollo.tbc.iit.edu/~spaceweather/data/cases/grid108/144/txt/channel_dataout_2013_144_0000.log`

to take the user to the file located at:

`/data1/public/cases/grid108/144/txt/channel_dataout_2013_144_0000.log`

When I placed this file into my htdocs folder and pointed my browser to `apollo.tbc.iit.edu/~spaceweather/channel_dataout_2013_144_0000.log` it displays the file in the browser just as expected.

The http://apollo.tbc.iit.edu/~spaceweather website is live and viewable to anyone who points their browser to it. So the link in the paragraph above will work just fine too and will display the file to the world.

Thank you for your help and please be  gentle.

--ZealotSveta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be overcomplicating things a little bit.

From what I understand, you need a symbolic link from your docroot to the data folder.

Create one using the following command:

```
mkdir -p /data1/home/spaceweather/htdoc/cases #just in case it does not exist
ln -s  /data1/public/cases /data1/home/spaceweather/htdoc/cases/data
```

This will create a symbolic link called "data" which will point to your /data1/public/cases directory.

If you `ls -l` in that directory you should see something like

```
data -> /data1/public/cases
```

Try to `cd` into the `data` directory to verify this worked.

---

*This shouldn't be necessary for you as you have it already in your .htaccess, but leaving it here for anyone else anyway:*

If this doesn't work through the web browser at first, you may need to add the `FollowSymLinks` to your htaccess: `Options +FollowSymLinks`. This tells Apache that it is OK to follow symbolic links such as the one you created.

Hope this helps. If I misunderstood your situation or requirements, please say so and I will edit appropriately.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. The server admin also suggested symbolic links. After trying this it seems like i can use this to get it to work.  All i will need to do is add another column in my database with the symbolic links rather than the actual directory path and link the symbolic link to the actual link and i'll be set.

Thank you so much.